# Is it possible to use other hand models in OVR hand tracking?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus, oculusquest

I am currently trying to develop with Oculus Quest Pro using the hand tracking feature. However, I want to change to material of the hand so that it looks more realistic. Is there some good way that I can deal with this? Like some usable textures that can be set on Oculus hand? Or some ways to replace models? Thanks a lot!

I find that the predefined hand here has a pretty complex skeleton. So, I think it won't be easy to find a compatible hand mesh. I have also tried to use another hand model directly by adding OVR custom skeleton to it. But the model is bending weirdly. I guess this is due to the improper weight of the skinning and different bone joints setting between models.